# how can I get the predict future following(next) value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, prediction

```
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), 0])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

train_size = int(len(signal_data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - int(len(signal_data) * 0.05)
val_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - test_size
train = signal_data[0:train_size]
val = signal_data[train_size:train_size+val_size]
test = signal_data[train_size+val_size:len(signal_data)]

x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_val, y_val = create_dataset(val, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)
```

I use `create_dataset` with `look_back=20`.

`signal_data` is preprocessed with min-max normalisation `MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))`.

Here is my model definition:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(l))

model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dropout(l))

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dropout(l))

model.add(Dense(1))
```

`x_test` shape is `(1340, 20, 1)` and

`y_test` shape is `(1340,)`

now... how can you get the following(next) value?

I want to get the next value like `model.predict` or etc...

I have `x_test` and `x_test[-1] == t` So, the meaning of the next value is t+1, t+2, .... t+n, in this example I want to get t+1, t+2 ... t+n

if you want to full source(including dataset) then you can see here https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/e1fc7d036356575f4d0799cdcebed90e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say `total_data` is your total dataset and `sc` is your `MinMaxScaler`. Then, after training the network you could predict next `n` values by doing the following.

```
inputs = total_data[len(total_data) - n - look_back:].values

inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(look_back, inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-look_back:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
```

`print predicted_stock_price.shape` would yield a shape of `(n, 1)` which is the number of values you want to predict.

Comment: Did you try the code? It predicts next `n` values from `look_back` number of values.

Comment: So you've set `n=20` and it does predict next `n` values right?

Comment: Maybe you could check whether the training is fine. However, this is the standard method of predicting next values of a stock market.

Comment: my model is https://imgur.com/niLk13X 
If you don't mind, may I ask where the source is from?

Comment: I have a new question If you don't mind me asking for help.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57550965/11309950